# Supported FPS in Camera2 API

Tags: android, range, frame-rate, android-camera2

I am trying to get supported Frames per second values from Camera2 API using below code.

```
CameraManager manager = (CameraManager)activity.getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
...
String cameraId = manager.getCameraIdList()[0];
CameraCharacteristics characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);
Range<Integer>[] fpsRanges = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.CONTROL_AE_AVAILABLE_TARGET_FPS_RANGES);
```

Developer site says `CONTROL_AE_AVAILABLE_TARGET_FPS_RANGES` is used to get list of frame rate ranges for `CaptureRequest#CONTROL_AE_TARGET_FPS_RANGE` supported by the camera device.

These are the values of fpsRange(upper and lower) array for Pixel2 mobile.

```
[15, 15], [24, 24], [7, 30], [30, 30], [7, 60], [60, 60]
```

Does this mean the above mentioned device supports Frame rates from 7 to 60 i.e. 7, 15, 24, 30 and 60? I am bit confused about these values.

Answer (score 1):

Please Take a look at this method, i get this from stackoverflow

```
private Range<Integer> getRange() {
    CameraCharacteristics chars = null;
    CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
    try {
        chars = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(mCameraId);
        Range<Integer>[] ranges = chars.get(CameraCharacteristics.CONTROL_AE_AVAILABLE_TARGET_FPS_RANGES);
        Range<Integer> result = null;
        for (Range<Integer> range : ranges) {
            int upper = range.getUpper();
            int lower = range.getLower();
            // 10 - min range upper for my needs
            Log.e("Upper fps :",""+upper);
            Log.e("range fps :",""+range);
            if (upper >= 10000) {
                if (result == null || upper < result.getUpper().intValue()) {
                    Range<Integer> newsrange = new Range<>(range.getLower()/1000,range.getLower()/1000);
                    result = newsrange;
                    Log.e("result fps :",""+range);

                }
            }
            if (upper >= 10) {
                if (result == null || upper < result.getUpper().intValue()) {
                    result = range;
                    Log.e("result fps :",""+range);

                }
            }
        }
        if (result == null) {
            result = ranges[0];
            Log.e("result in range[0] is :",""+result);
        }
        return result;
    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

How to use ??? 
1. in createCameraPreviewSession() at mCameraDevice.createCaptureSession :

```
mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_TARGET_FPS_RANGE,getRange());
```

2. in method CaptureStiilPicture() -> set brignes after capture builder

   captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_TARGET_FPS_RANGE,(getRange()));

Comment: Thanks @Yudi karma for the response. But my question is the how to get list of support FPSs from the result of characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.CONTROL_AE_AVAILABLE_TARGET_FPS_RANGES);. Result : [15, 15], [24, 24], [7, 30], [30, 30], [7, 60], [60, 60]. As per your code getRange function returns 15 FPS even though the device might support 30 and 60 FPS.

Comment: Also, in the function you get minimum FPS value from the Range array I guess.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the range of FPS, that the camera 2 api can use.

This is mainly used to adjust the exposure time properly. If you choose the range [30, 30], your exposure time can't be higher than 0.033..s. This results in bad performance in dark light-conditions, but it allows you to have a fixed frame rate.
On the other hand [30, 7] allows the api more freedom for the adjustment of the frame rate and thus also of the exposure time.

I am not sure if this is an issue on all api-levels, but api 23 will result in very dark pictures, if you fix the range to a specific value.

Hope it helps